# Ruby Rails : Saving JSON and Parsing it back to Boolean values in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

> EDIT: I need go get in my view the `boolean` `true/false` from my database, but the problem is, upon calling it from the databse its returning a `string`. The `datatype` of my `json_permissions` is `json`. As I read and suggested by others `boolean` `true/false` is a valid json and on save its being saved as a `Hash` already (which is true because on debug it'll have the `Hash` format I'll show below).

If I debug and look at my param form data before `.to_json` this is what it looks like:

[image: Form Data Params]

I parsed it like so (ActiveAdmin):

```
member_action :update_permissions, method: :put do
   resource.json_permissions = JSON.parse(params.to_json)
   resource.save
   redirect_to admin_group_path(resource)
end
```

> EDIT: I'm saving the resource like this now (explanation from [.to_json vs JSON.parse](https://imantung.github.io/to-json-vs-json-parse/):

```
member_action :update_permissions, method: :put do
   resource.json_permissions = params.to_json
   resource.save
   redirect_to admin_group_path(resource)
end
```

On debug, it's already a hash:

binding.pry params before `.to_json`
[image]

On the console after `.to_json`, I can see that this is being `stringi-fied` (any way to prevent this?)

```
[["json_permissions", "{\"utf8\":\"✓\",\"_method\":\"put\",\"authenticity_token\":\"kjRYKDQZAMCZPvw/jQZvh0pyCPJ11Q30zROdh8WVohI=\",\"view_accounts\":\"true\",\"view_admin\":\"true\",\"view_admin_users\":\"true\",\"add_edit_admin_users\":\"true\",\"view_groups\":\"true\",\"add_edit_groups\":\"true\",\"view_jobs\":\"true\",\"view_reports\":\"true\",,\"commit\":\"Update Group Permissions\",\"action\":\"update_permissions\",\"controller\":\"admin/groups\",\"id\":\"3\"}"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-09 05:28:19.859162"]]
```

Then in my `show` for view in Rails:

```
show do
    resource.json_permissions.each do |key, value|
     if value == "true" || value == "false"
       resource.json_permissions[key] = !!value
     end
    end
    resource.save
    render('admin/groups/show', { group: group})
end
```

> EDIT: I changed my code to the following to make sure I'm re-assigning a `boolean` `true/false` on the `model` before `save` again.

```
show do
  resource.json_permissions.each do |key, value|
    if value == "true"
        resource.json_permissions[key] = true
    elsif value == "false"
        resource.json_permissions[key] = false
    end
    resource.save
  end      
  binding.pry
  render('admin/groups/show', { group: group})
end
```

On binding.pry before save - inside the loop right before `resource.save` it's now changing to `boolean`:

```
#<Group id: 3, group_name: "Treasury", group_description: "Treasury Department", active: true, created_at: "2018-10-23 06:08:48", updated_at: "2018-11-09 05:28:19", created_by: "maria.mendoza@sci.ph", updated_by: "maria.mendoza@sci.ph", json_permissions: {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"kjRYKDQZAMCZPvw/jQZvh0pyCPJ11Q30zROdh8WVohI=", "view_accounts"=>true, "view_bank_accounts"=>true, "add_edit_bank_accounts"=>true, "view_recipient_accounts"=>true,.... >
```

On binding.pry checking the contents of `resource/group` after save again, now with the correct `boolean` values.
[image]

Sadly, using `double bang` operator before saving it again for the view,

> Still returns a `Hash` string value on `true/false`

Upon checking the database - it's true that it is still saved as a string, so no wondering now why it's not getting the `boolean` `true/false` on my debug after save.

```
{
"add_edit_admin_users": "false",
"view_user_accounts": "false",
"view_reports": "false",
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Does this have something to do on `save` that converts it back to `string` ?

My form looks like this on `POST`

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, resource], url: update_permissions_admin_group_path(resource), method: :put) do |f| %>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel_contents">
        <div class="attributes_table">
            <ul class="tree" id="tree">
                <li>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'view_accounts', false %>
                    <%= check_box_tag 'view_accounts', checked = true %> View Accounts 
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'view_bank_accounts', false %>
                        <%= check_box_tag 'view_bank_accounts', checked = true %> View Bank Accounts </li>
                        <li>
```

> EDIT: Explicitly re-assigning a `boolean` does the TRICK :)

Comment: Where is your JSON coming from? Booleans are valid JSON values.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej directly from formdata params I'll edit what my form looks like

Comment: Well, it's not really JSON then, unless you're catching the form submits with JavaScript and sending it using AJAX. What's the purpose for dumping your params into JSON and parsing them into a hash again?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej hmmm yeah just getting everything using params and not sending it via javascript jquery. the datatype where it is saved is of json datatype. while i need to hash it so I can use it back on my read view for the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
show do
   resource.json_permissions.each do |key, value|
       if value == "true"
           resource.json_permissions[key] = true
       elsif value == "false"
           resource.json_permissions[key] = false
       end
       resource.save
     end      
     binding.pry
     render('admin/groups/show', { group: group})
end
```

Explicitly converting it to boolean like so does the trick for some reason. Even though upon checking my database the `true/false` is still saved as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
!!string
```

will always return `true`:

```
!!"false" # true
!!"true"  # true
```

You can write your assignment as

```
resource.json_permissions[key][value] = ( value == "true" )
```

parenthesis are optional, but they increase readability.

Comment: it's from "true" I need to make as bool true that's why I made it `!!value` and save it like that - but that is where the error of implicit conversion comes in

Comment: @Theresa if you assign a result of comparison (`value == "true"`) you will assign proper booleans.

Comment: ah! alright let me check that! it's my first time using the double bang operation must've misunderstood how it's used

Comment: Well, it's twice the negation. In Ruby, anything but `nil` and `false` is truthy. So only `!!nil` and `!!false` will evaluate to false, everything else will be true.